# Remove axes from a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, axes

Is it possible to remove the axes from a `pyplot.figure()`?

Using the `pyplot.imsave()` to create an image without axes works OK

```
plt.imsave(file, zi)
```

[image: Image produces with pyplot.imsave()]

but it's limited because it only works with grid data.

When I use `pyplot.figure()` and save it using `pyplot.savefig()` as follows

```
...
# create figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1.0,1.0))
# apply contour plot
plt.contour(zi,15,linewidths=0.1,colors='k')
plt.contourf(zi,15,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
# flip the y-axis
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[::-1])
# save to file, 256x256 pixels
plt.savefig(file1, dpi=256)
```

[image: Image produces with pyplot.savefix()]

the saved image keeps it's axis, as seen on image above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to remove the axis display and any spacing that was allocated to the axis with the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1.0,1.0))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.0, -0.2, 1.2, 1.2])
plt.contour(zi,15,linewidths=0.1,colors='k')
plt.contourf(zi,15,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[::-1])
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.savefig(file1, dpi=256)
```

Comment: Could you describe what module did you import and how did you import them?

Comment: This did not remove the space allocated to the axis for me. I fixed that by using a negative subplot adjust!